# Add "Forgot Password" link in Windows Auth. Page

Tags: 2010, sharepoint-server, windows-authentication, password

Like on the FBA Login Page, can we add" Forgot Password" link in Windows Auth. Page?

How can this be done?

Answer (score 1):

If you web app is claims based then yes you can customize it.

> In a Claims-mode web app, the Windows Authentication is handled by
>   /_windows/default.aspx. If we check the path of the virtual folder
>   /_windows, it points to C:\Program Files\Common Files\Microsoft
>   Shared\Web Server Extensions\14\TEMPLATE\IDENTITYMODEL\WINDOWS.
>   Obviously, modifying the files in this folder directly is not a good
>   idea. So what I did first is to create another folder, copy all files
>   (default.aspx and web.config) in the above folder to the folder I
>   created, and modify the path of the virtual folder to point to the new
>   folde

complete steps mentioned here:
http://blogs.msdn.com/b/chunliu/archive/2010/09/21/creating-a-custom-login-page-for-windows-authentication.aspx

Comment: How Can We Point newly created Page for Windows Authentication?

Comment: as i mentioned and blog also saying you have to customize the /_windows/default.aspx

Comment: ",and modify the path of the virtual folder to point to the new folder"----I did not get this point.

Comment: what i believe you dont need to change the path rather just make the copied of the current files.

Comment: Ya.I Created New Folder Named Windows1 & Copies 2 Files From Windows Folder. Now How to Access this Page?

Comment: I think we confused the thing...copying files mean we want to take backup of files so that if we corrupt original files then can restore from backup....Now you have to customize the page according to your need as he did in his blog

Comment: OK.I did that.I had added one Label.But it not shows Up.